# creating a list of dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

from the given input

```
lists = ["7ee57f24", "deadbeef"]
```

I want to get the following output

```
l1': [
   {
   'd': 
         {
            'id': '7ee57f24'
         }
   },
   {
   'd': 
         {
            'id': 'deadbeed'
         }
   }
]
```

I have tried this code

```
    lists = ["7ee57f24", "deadbeef"]
    l1 = {"d":[{"id": lis} for lis in lists]}
    print(l1)
```

but it gives me wrong output

```
{'d': [{'id': '7ee57f24'}, {'id': 'deadbeef'}]}
```

Comment: is `l1` a list or a dict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
lists = ["7ee57f24", "deadbeef"]
l1 = [
    {"d": {"id": id_}}
    for id_ in lists
]
print(l1)
```

Output:

```py
[{'d': {'id': '7ee57f24'}}, {'d': {'id': 'deadbeef'}}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain what I was missing

Comment: @kharevbv, You were trying to put dicts in a dictionary when you really wanted to put dicts in a list.